# Adding an S to the end of business name. What's proper

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if adding an S to the end of a business name is correct. Here's the example ABC Dumpster. Should it be ABC Dumpster or ABC Dumpsters

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question doesn't say why you're adding random letters to company names. Some might go so far as to say *that ain't proper* :) . Please edit to provide more context.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it is unclear what you're asking. Once you've edited to provide context, feel free to ping me about reversing my close-vote. You can do that by adding a comment that includes *@Lawrence*.

Comment: You can name anything you like however you like; there is no grammar to it. Whether a name is appropriate for your company is really a matter of opinion, and will vary greatly on your location, industry, customer base, and so forth. Unfortunately, our format is very ill-suited to such questions. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're thinking of a business that sells items. Both the singular and the plural are correct. You can think of yourself as ABC Dumpster because you're in the dumpster business or you could be ABC Dumpsters because you sell dumpsters.

[This list](https://www.sec.gov/rules/other/4-460list.htm) from the SEC shows how different companies approach this question. For example, you can see the singular "Brown Shoe Company" and the plural "International Business Machines."